# Как осуществляется обновление данных при работе сокетами?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, websocket, ratchet

пишу на php. Использую Ratchet с ZMQ для работы с вебсокетами . Пытаюсь осуществить обновление списка заказов в админке в реальном времени , когда клиент  успешно сделал заказ . Все почти реализовал : постоянное соеденение между браузером и сервером есть , данные отлично приходят , но вот на самом процессе обновления списка заказов немножко есть недопонимания . Как оно реализуется ? Вот смотрите : припустим админ заходит на страницу , соединяется с сервером , с помощью некого js-скрипта подписывается на определенные события и ждет данных от сервера . При заказе , сервер получает те самые данные от клиента(имя , телефон и так далее) и отправляет админу. А как те данные использывать то ? Была мысль просто с помощью jquery вставлять эти данные в html код , а именно в таблице с заказами создавать новую строку с этими данными , но это довольно таки геморойно и , как по мне , не правильно . Или правильно ? Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: А в чем проблема то? Получили данные, добавили в DOM. Пусть это jQuery, или AngularJS, или ReactJS. Ничем не отличает от работы через AJAX. Только транспортом

Comment: ну в ajax можно и весь div обновлять  ,а вот через сокеты , как я знаю , нельзя

Comment: А как одно с другим связанно? AJAX и сокеты это всего лишь трансфер, после получения данных вы вольны делать все, что угодно

Answer (score 1):

А в чем заключается сложность? У вас все правильно. А по передаче данных можно сделать так:

Вы через веб-сокеты отправляете номер заказа клиента при совершении заказа и при получении номера заказа от клиента делаете внутри администраторской панели запрос на внутреннее API для получения данных по заказу *(например: /orders/{orderId})*, и вставляете в таблицу интерфейса заказ или выводите всплывающее окно, что был получен новый заказ.

Конечно можно отправлять всю информацию по заказу через веб-сокет, но по сути не всегда нужна вся информация по заказу для оповещения, а по ID можно получить все требуемые данные.